# Regex max number 11 and must 2 digits

Tags: regex

I have a validation expression i'm trying to figure out.  First, I want the user to only be allowed to enter the max number of 11...not 11 characters but the number allow is the max that can be entered.  I got that to work with the code below and works fine.

```
ValidationExpression="^([1-9]|[0-1][0-1])$"
```

However, I want the user to also be forced to use 2 digits.  For example, instead of 1 they need to enter 01.  I've tried different ways of doing this but can't seem to get it to work.

I tried this as well but that didn't work either.

```
ValidationExpression="^([1-9]|[0-1][0-1])${2}"
```

Comment: To match `01`-`11` use `ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[01])$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you had better to write your expression as an answer, it's the right answer.

Comment: @Luis Good, I posted then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to perform this in a single step (i.e. you can't do a `<` and `>` check as well as a regex) then this should do it:

```
ValidationExpression="^(?:0\d|1[01])$"
```

Or, if your language doesn't recognise the `\d` symbol:

```
ValidationExpression="^(?:0[0-9]|1[01])$"
```

"Match either (0 followed by any digit) or (1 followed by 0 or 1), anchored at the beginning and end of the input string."

Answer (score 2):

To match padded 2-digit numbers from `01` to `12` you may use

```
ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[01])$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FUHts0/1).

The expression matches:

- `^`
- `(` - start of a group (here, a capturing group is used for better readability, a non-capturing one can also be used)

  - `0` -  zero
  - `[1-9]`  - `1` to `9` digit
  - `|`  - or
  - `1`  - `1`
  - `[01]` - `0` or `1` digit
- `)`  - end of group
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
/\b(?:[0][\d]|[1][01])\b/
```

This says enter a number `0` followed by `0-9` or enter `1` followed by `0` or `1`. It is bounded on both sides by word boundaries and it is a non-capturing group. Try it out [here](http://regexr.com/3ei2g).

Comment: This will also match "00 00"

Comment: @ardavey I know. OP didn't saying anything about not matching `00`. Won't yours also match `00`?

Comment: @ardavey Oh you mean separated by a space? I know. That was also intentional.

Comment: different interpretations of the OP's post, I guess - I reasonably assumed that anything that's not a 2-digit string is invalid input.

Comment: @ardavey Agreed. I think both answers are correct because OP didn't provide any parameters for it. I thought that OP was trying to match things like `00 14 01 32 10` and get 3 matches.

Comment: Probably I'm wrong, but isn't `\d` equivalent to `[0-9]` and cannot be in between `[` and `]` characters?

Comment: @LuisColorado You're half right. `\d` is equivalent to `0-9` but nothing prohibits it from being between `[` and `]`. `[\d]` is the same thing as `\d`. I like to use `[\d]` in a scenario like this because I think it makes it a little clearer that `|` is not a part of `\d`.